# Ubuntu server Release 22.04.3 LTS NVIDIA issue after upgrade

Tags: server, nvidia, kernel, vmware, gpu-driver

I have been in a jam for some time and have been trying endlessly to address the issue with the NVIDIA quadro card that was working previously before June 2023.

After an upgrade took place, my PMS, EMby showed that no GPU was available.

Currently running:

```
Release 22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) 64-bit
Kernel Linux 6.4.11-060411-generic x86_64
```

Kernel was updated FORCEFULLY this past week and was able to get rid of some errors as shown below:

1. Possible missing firmware although firmware is installed
2. Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/* for module i915

Now after extensive retracing of my steps, I tried the following to verify if INDEED I got the intra upgraded with `update-initramfs -u -k all`:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
linux-firmware is already the newest version (20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.18).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
root@eden:/home/anima# update-initramfs -u -k all
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.4.11-060411-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-26-generic
```

I restarted the server, retried manually installing the the nvidia drivers, and I always get the possible missing firmware issue. Also, I went to ran software and updates and tried selecting a driver I used back in 2022, nvidia-driver-470 (proprietary). This again showed as failed while updating.

I honestly have dedicated more to reading and trial and error but have been unsuccessful.

Also had to uninstall VMWARE due to the upgrade and stating a GCC error. (I assume it is related)

Anyone willing to share their time to guide me further into the rabbit hole with this one? I would appreciate it vm.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server uses the *stable* GA kernel stack which is 5.15, with the HWE kernel stack option at 6.2, what you mention is only a *testing* kernel and not a *stable* kernel option for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Are you using Ubuntu? or a system based on Ubuntu Server?

Comment: sorry for the delay, we just arrived back and i saw the response. Yes, I am on UBuntu Server. The information provided was what im currently at now. The system flagged that these updates were available and did it. I tried downgrading the Kernel to 5.15 and saw no fix for both the VMWARE or the nvidia issue. Because of this, I did an upgrade to 6.4.11-060411. Do you suggest i downgrade the Kernel again, to the one you mentioned and retry? 

I did a manual install of course using the sudo commands and it came back as the errors mentioned above.

Comment: still need help with this issue